# Validate PlaceAutocompleteFragment in android

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to validate a PlaceAutocompleteFragment in android. I would like to add a toast if it is empty, if it is not empty then I want to do some processing. Here is my PlaceAutocompleteFragment. Is there an event listener I can attach to validate if no Place is selected?

FYI this is the Google Places API for Android

```
final PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.           
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i("An error occured: " , status.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use place autocomplete request in place of using fragment like this

```
 public void openPlaceAutoComplete() {
    try {
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .build(getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and you can get results like this on activity result method ...

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getActivity(), data);
                setAddress(place.getAddress().toString(), place.getLatLng().latitude,
                        place.getLatLng().longitude);
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getActivity(), data);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No places Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a latLng variable globally.

```
LatLng latLngPickup = null

@Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place. 
        //Place place = places.get(0);
        latLngPickup = place.getLatLng();

    }
```

Whenever you want to check if user has selected the place, check like this

```
if (latLngPickup == null) {
        // your alert \\
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback.Do I add the condition inside the onPlaceSelected method or outside? I am getting errors when I try to add it outside of method but the Toast doesnt show if I add it within the method

Comment: Add the method outside whenever you want to check whether user has selected the place or, can you please log this (latLngPickup.latitude and latlngPickup.longitude) and let me know

Comment: Yeah the error I get when I try that is 

Unknown Class: 'latLngPickup'

There ie an error on the return also saying 

Return outside method

Comment: can you post the code in which you have tried mine?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry I had to add my code as an answer, I cant add a comment in reply to yours Rahul

Here is my code

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
             LatLng latLngPickup = null;
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {  
                    latLngPickup=place.getLatLng();
                  }
                if(latLngPickup.latitude == null) {
                    Toast error = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select a location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    error.show();
                    return;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Status status) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                        Log.i("An error occured: " , status.toString());
                    }
                });
```